# My database is not updating

Tags: php, sql, database

So,

I am a beginning 'nerd' and my job is now to make a kind of schedule where people can put their name in the input. I work with JS with the following code:

```
var timeoutId; $('form input').on('input propertychange change', function() {
console.log('Invoer bewerking');
clearTimeout(timeoutId);
timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
    saveToDB();
}, 1000); }); function saveToDB() {  console.log('Opslaan naar Database');
form = $('.formulier24');
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: form.serialize(),
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        $('.HowAbout').html('Opslaan...');
    },
    success: function(data) { console.error(data) ;
        var jqObj = jQuery(data); 
        var d = new Date();
        $('.HowAbout').html('Opgeslagen om: ' + d.toLocaleTimeString());
    },
}); } $('.formulier24').submit(function(e) {
saveToDB();
e.preventDefault(); });
```

and the AJAX file is as the following code:

```
<?php include ('connect.php'); if(isset($_POST['formulier24'])) {
$userName = $_POST['userName'];
$hours = $_POST['hours'];
$sql = "UPDATE evenement SET userName = '$userName' WHERE hours = '$hours'";
mysql_select_db('u7105d15197_main');
$retval = mysql_query($sql, $conn);

if (!$retval) {
    die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo " Updated data successfully\n";

mysql_close($conn); } ?>
```

The website says it is saving, but the updated information won't show up in the database. Does anybody know what I am doing wrong in this situation? P.S. it is a auto update form without a button.

Comment: Not php-savvy, but is this correct? `$sql = "UPDATE evenement SET userName = '$userName' WHERE hours = '$hours'` Aren't you using `$params` as literals this way?

Comment: I dont know bro, someone told me to do it like that ghehe..

Comment: first update mysql to mysqli or pdo
$sql = "UPDATE evenement SET userName = '$userName' WHERE hours = '$hours'";
then echo $sql;
die();
then check alert , run this query in phpmyadmin

Comment: You're using insecure and unmaintained database functions that have been deprecated for almost a decade. Stop it now. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: Ohh. Thanks for sharing @miken32. I am going to make it all mysqli (I guess)

Comment: I'd recommend PDO, much easier and more modern object-oriented syntax.

Comment: You're updating a record, does that record exist to be updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your problem is that your `UPDATE` query is trying to update a row that doesn't exist. A `REPLACE` query will insert data, or replace it if there is a conflict with a table key.

While you're fixing that, you may as well toss out the code you have above. Give me 30 seconds with that web page and I could erase your whole database. (For example, what would happen if someone posted `Hours` as `foo' OR 1=1 OR 'foo`?)

It's a matter of personal preference, but I find [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) much easier to work with. It's less verbose and allows for much easier building of [prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/1255289), which are an essential security measure for any web application. It also allows you to use modern error handling methods like [exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php).

```
<?php
/* this block could be in a separate include file if it's going to be reused */
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_name = "u7105d15197_main";
$db_user = "user";
$db_pass = "asldkfjwlekj";
$db_opts = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE          => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
);
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name;charset=utf8mb4", $db_user, $db_pass, $db_opts);


if(isset($_POST['formulier24'])) {
    $sql = "REPLACE INTO evenement SET userName = ?, hours = ?";
    $parameters = array($_POST["userName"], $_POST["hours"]);
    try {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $result = $stmt->execute($parameters);
        $return = "Updated data successfully!";
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $return = "Could not update data! Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    echo json_encode($return);
}
```